# Finding inflection points of the function $\sqrt[3]{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been working on a problem where I have to find critical number and inflection point for the function $\sqrt[3]{x}$

While I have been able to find critical number, I'm not sure how to find the inflection point for the function as for this particular function I cannot assign double derivative to be zero and then solve for x. The double derivative for other points indicates that the inflection point is between -1 and 1, but I'm not able to find any more ideas on how to approach this.

$f''(-1) = 2/9 > 0$

$f''(1) = -2/9 < 0$

Comment: $$x=0\\continues \\but - not - differentiable \to $$it is inflection point

Comment: and what about the second derivative at $x=0$?

Comment: It is not necessary to have $f''<\infty$ . it suffices to have the same sign at the point. in this case $$f''(0)\to +\infty$$

Comment: @Khosrotash The definition which I'm using from my books says that $f''(x)$ needs to be defined at the interior of the interval: https://psibi.in/velleman-calculus/chapter4/section4.html#sec-1-3 to figure out the concave up/down part. And I'm not exactly sure how to figure out the inflection point without finding the interval where it is concave up/down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inflection point is $(0,0)$. To see this, note that $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ is twice differentiable on $\mathbb R^*  =\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$:

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]{x^2}}, f''(x) = - \frac{2}{9\sqrt[3]{x^5}} .$$

$f$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$ (but it has the improper derivative $+\infty$ at $0$, see for example [Having trouble understanding condition for Rolle's Theorem (russian translation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3429876)).

You can now apply 1.3 Theorem 4.4.3 to see that $f$ is concave up on $(-\infty,0]$ and concave down on $[0,\infty)$. According to 1.4 Definition 4.4.4 the point $(0,0)$ is the only inflection point of $f$.

Intuitively this is clear if we look at $f''$: We have $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f''(x) =  -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f''(x) =  +\infty$, i.e. $f''$ has an "improper change of sign" at $0$.

**Update:**

You can also easily prove the following theorem:

> Let $f : I \to J$ be a bijection between to real intervals. Then $(a,f(a))$ is an inflection point of $f$ if and only $(f(a),a)$ is an inflection point of $f^{-1} : J \to I$.

This true because the graph of $f^{-1}$ is obtained from ther graph of $f$ by a reflection at the diagonal line $y = x$.

In your example $f^{-1}(x) = x^3$ which has exactly one inflection point at $(0,0)$.

Comment: How can you apply theorem 4.4.3 when we know that $f''(x)$ is not defined for $x=0$ ?

Comment: @Sibi "Suppose $f$ is continuous on an interval $I$ and twice differentiable on the interior of $I$". In our case the interior does not contain $0$. Recall that there are quite a number of theorems which require continuity on some interval $I$, but do not require the exitence of derivatives in the boundary points of $I$. An example is Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.