# what does Fermat's theorem bother with infinite derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I don't understand the last paragraph , what does Fermat's theorem bother with infinite derivative? Anyone can give a clear explanation ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It appears that the author allows infinite derivatives (such as saying that $f'(0)=-\infty$ for $f(x)=-\sqrt[3]x$). However, the proof shows that at $c$, difference quotients are non-postive to the right and non-negative to the left of $c$, hence the limit, *if* it exists, must be both non-positive and non-negative (hence zero) - even if we *a priori* allow infinite limits

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [Having trouble understanding condition for Rolle's Theorem (russian translation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3429876). However, in the linked question it is assumed that $f$ is differentiable in *all* interior points $c$ of the interval. *Differentiable* means that $\lim_{x\to c} \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ exists - either being finite or one of $\pm \infty$.

In the above proof it is shown that $\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \le 0$ for $x > c$ and $\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} \ge 0$ for $x < c$. Thus, **if** $f'(c) = \lim_{x\to c} \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ exists, then this limit must be $0$.

Therefore in the theorem one can replace the assumption "If at this point there exists a finite derivative $f'(c)$" by "If at this point there exists a derivative $f'(c)$".